# Realm query problem with sorted localized data

Tags: swift, database-design, localization, realm

Consider the following Realm models:

```swift
class Fruit: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    let localizations = List<Localization>()

    /** 
        Returns the localized name of the fruit matching the preferred language of the app 
        or self.name if the fruit does not have a localization matching the user preferred language codes. 
    */
    var localizedName: String? {
        guard !Locale.isPreferredLanguageDefaultAppLanguage else { return self.name }

        let preferredLanguagesCodes = Locale.preferredLanguagesCodes
        let localizations = preferredLanguagesCodes.compactMap({ languageCode in Array(self.localizations).filter({ $0.languageCode == languageCode }).first })
        return localizations.first?.localizedName ?? self.name
    }
}

class Localization: Object {
    @objc dynamic var localizedName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var languageCode: String = ""
}
```

Let's say I have 2 fruits in my database (represented in JSON format for the sake of simplicity):

```
[
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "localizations": [
            {
                "localizedName": "Pomme",
                "languageCode": "fr"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Banana",
        "localizations": [
            {
                "localizedName": "Banane",
                "languageCode": "fr"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

Now I want to get all the fruits in my database, and sort them alphabetically by their `localizedName`.

```swift
var localizedNameSortingBlock: ((Fruit, Fruit) -> Bool) = {
    guard let localizedNameA = $0.localizedName, let localizedNameB = $1.localizedName else { return false }
    return localizedNameA.diacriticInsensitive < localizedNameB.diacriticInsensitive
}

let sortedFruits = Array(Realm().objects(Fruit.self)).sorted(by: localizedNameSortingBlock)
```

If the first preferred language of my device is "English", I get this:

1. Apple
2. Banana

If it's set to "French":

1. Banane
2. Pomme

It's quite simple, but this solution has a major inconvenient:

By casting the `Results<Fruit>` collection into an array, I'm loosing the ability to get live updates via Realm's notification token system.

The problem is, I can't sort using `NSPredicate` directly on the Results collection, because the `localizedName` property is a computed property, thus is ignored by Realm.

I thought about writing the `localizedName` value directly into the `name` property of the `Fruit` object, but doing so requires to loop through all fruits and change their name whenever the user change of preferred language. There must be a better way.

So my question is:

#### Is there a way to retrieve all the fruits in my database, get them sorted by their `localizedName`, without loosing the ability to receive batch updates from Realm?